# If a prime can be expressed as sum of square of two integers, then prove that the representation is unique.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, sums-of-squares

If a prime can be expressed as sum of two squares, then prove that the representation is unique.

My attempt:
If $a^2+b^2=p$, then it is obvious that $a,b$ of different parity.
Now, I assume the contraposition that the representation is not unique, $p=a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$. Again, $c,d$ are of different parity.

Now, let $b,d$ be even and $a,c$ be odd.

So, $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2 \implies a^2-c^2=d^2-b^2 \implies (a+c)(a-c)=(d-b)(d+b)$.

I cannot proceed any further. Please help.

Comment: Nitpick corner case: $2 = 1^2 + 1^2$, so not necessarily of different parity.  This would most likely be taken care of in a different case. :)

Comment: @anorton That is definitely something I didn't think about...thanks for identification

Answer (score 18):

The slickest way is via a little Algebraic Number Theory. If $p=a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$ then $$p=(a+bi)(a-bi)=(c+di)(c-di)$$ Now ${\bf Z}[i]$ is a unique factorization domain, so these two factorizations of $p$ show that $a+bi$ can't be a prime in ${\bf Z}[i]$. We must have a non-trivial factorization $a+bi=(s+ti)(u+vi)$, whence $a-bi=(s-ti)(u-vi)$, and then $$p=(s^2+t^2)(u^2+v^2)$$ contradicting primality of $p$.

There are ways to answer your question without these advanced concepts, but I can never remember how it's done. I'm sure someone else will.

Comment: Thanks for the approach...I will try to do something with this.

Comment: How do you deduce that $a+bi$ is not prime from the UFD property of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

Comment: @Cary, maybe it would be better to say that $a+bi$ and $c+di$ can't both be prime (in ${\bf Z}[i]$), since that would give us two different prime factorizations of $p$. Then without loss of generality we may assume $a+bi$ is not prime.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: if $p$ is an ordinary prime, then $p$ is either a Gauss prime or the product of a Gauss prime and its conjugate. Clearly, we are in the latter case. Can't we just say that if $p=(a+bi)(a-bi)=(c+di)(c-di)$ are two prime factorizations, then $a+bi=u(c+di)$ or $a+bi=u(c-di)$ for $u$ a unit. In either case, we have $(a,b)=(\pm c, \pm d)$ or $(a,b) = (\pm d, \pm c)$, which implies $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$?

Comment: @Cary, I was trying to do it using just the UFD property, and not the result about how rational primes factor in the Gaussian integers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: sorry, I'm just trying understand your proof, and as far as I understand, the fact that I mentioned in the last comment implies that an ordinary prime $p$ cannot be written as the product of three Gaussian primes. However you represented $p$ as a product of at least 3 Gaussian primes.

Comment: @Cary, yes, under the assumption that $p$ has two distinct representations as a sum of two squares. Of course, that assumption proves to be false, so it turns out that $p$ is not a product of three (or more) Gaussian primes.

Answer (score 10):

Here's an answer without Algebraic Number Theory. I found it in Shanks, Solved and Unsolved Problems in Number Theory.

Assume $$p=a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2\tag1$$ with all variables positive integers. Then $$p^2=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=a^2c^2+a^2d^2+b^2c^2+b^2d^2$$ and you can verify by just multiplying everything out that $$p^2=(ac+bd)^2+(ad-bc)^2\tag2$$ and $$p^2=(ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2\tag3$$ By (1), we have $$(p-a^2)d^2=(p-c^2)b^2$$ which implies $$p(d^2-b^2)=(ad-bc)(ad+bc)\tag4$$ From (4), $p$ divides $ad-bc$, or $p$ divides $ad+bc$. If $p$ divides $ad-bc$, then from (2) we get $ad-bc=0$, so $d^2-b^2=0$, so $b=d$. If $p$ divides $ad+bc$, then from (3) we get $ac=bd$. Now $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, so $a$ divides $d$, and $b$ divides $c$. Then by (1) we have $a=d$, and we have proved that the two representations of $p$ are the same.

This is probably something like what @Konstantinos was getting at in his answer.

Comment: Just noting that $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac+bd)^2+(ad-bc)^2=(ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2$ states that if a number is the product of two sums of squares,then the number can also be written as the sum of two squares.This is the sum of squares identity of Diophantus.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is trivialized if you are given that $x^2+y^2=n$ has $r_2(n)=4\sum_{d|n} \sin(\pi d/2) $ solutions in the integers.

The number of ways $r_2(p)=4\sum_{d|p} \sin(\frac{\pi d}{2})=4(1+\sin(\pi p/2))$.

If $\sin(\pi p /2)=1$ then there are 8 solution in the integers. Namely, $(\pm a,\pm b)$ and $(\pm b, \pm a)$ satisfy $x^2+y^2=p$ where $a\neq b$. There is another way one might imagine $8$ solutions: $(0,\pm a),(\pm a,0)$ and $(\pm b,\pm b)$ but this cannot happen because it would mean that $p$ is a perfect square and therefore not prime.

If $\sin(\pi p /2)=-1$ then we cannot write $p$ as the sum of squares.

$If \sin(\pi p /2)=0$ then $p=2$.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the same as Gerry Myerson's proof but employing [known properties of Gaussian primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer#Gaussian_primes):

Suppose $p=a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$ for some integers $a,b,c,d>0$. Assume, additionally, that $a$ and $c$ are odd whereas $b$ and $d$ are even. We must show $a=c$ and $b=d$.

We know $$p=(a+bi)(a-bi)=(c+di)(c-di),$$
where all the Gaussian integers appearing are primes. Thus, by unique factorization in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$,
\begin{equation}a+bi=u\begin{cases}c+di\\
c-di\end{cases},\tag{1}\end{equation}
where $u$ is a unit of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, that is, $u\in \{1,-1,i,-i\}$. Finally, we divide into the four possible cases for $u$:

1. $\color{blue}{u=1}$. Forces $a+bi=c+di$, and the result follows.
2. $\color{blue}{u=-1}$. This case is impossible because RHS in $(1)$ would have negative real part, while LHS has positive real part ($a>0$).
3. $\color{blue}{u=i}$. Then $a+bi=d+ci$ by positiveness, but this contradicts the chosen parity of $a,b,c,d$.
4. $\color{blue}{u=-i}$. Impossible because RHS in $(1)$ would have negative imaginary part.

Answer (score -1):

If $p=a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$ then $$p=\frac{(ac+bd)(ac-bd)}{(a+d)(a-d)}$$

Comment: How is that supposed to help?

Comment: It is a contradiction this shows that $p$ must be composite.Maybe i will edit it later when i will have time!

Comment: Had any time, Konstantinos?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson . What is the matter with you? It is not the first time you are trying to be ironic to me and others as well.

Comment: Sorry, Konstantinos, I didn't know that trying to be ironic shows something is the matter with me.

Comment: It surely does show. I am happy you learned this from me.

Comment: By the way, I couldn't find any previous interaction between us on this website. Are you sure I tried to be ironic to you on some earlier occasion?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson There was a question at MathOverflow, but the comments were deleted (probably from the moderators).

Comment: I'll take your word for it. Meanwhile, concerning the post here, one user is on record as not seeing how it helps, and three others (not me!) upvoted that comment. Only one user has voted your post up, balanced by one who has voted it down (again, not me!). So I'd say there's something approaching a consensus that your answer needs some editing if it's going to be helpful to other users. I hope you will find the time to do that editing.