# On sums of primes

Tags: number-theory

If $p$ is a prime number expressible as $x^2$ + $1$, is it possible to rewrite $p$ as $p$=$a^2$ + $b^2$ where $a,b >1$?  If so can you give me an example?

Comment: Can you show some investigation attempts on this problem. For example, have you checked to see if this is possible for some non-prime numbers?

Comment: No, you don't understand the question.

Comment: @Shailesh jevie wants a new representation not the excisting one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/719700/if-a-prime-can-be-expressed-as-sum-of-square-of-two-integers-then-prove-that-th/719803#719803) where it is shown that if $n$ can be expressed as a sum of two squares in two ways then $n$ must be composite.

I think it was Mersenne who was first to prove this but I am not sure.

(So, the answer to your question is NO)