# Prove $x^n-p$ is irreducible over $Z[i]$ where $p$ is an odd prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Prove $x^n-p$ is irreducible over $Z[i]$ where $p$ is an odd prime.

By gausses lemma this is equivalent to irreducability over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$. Using field extensions this is easy. $[\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[n]{p}):\mathbb{Q}(i)][\mathbb{Q}(i):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[n]{p}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{p})][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{p}):\mathbb{Q}]=2n$ Thus $[\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[n]{p}):\mathbb{Q}(i)]=n$ and so $x^n-p$ must be the minimal polynomial, and so it is irreducible. However, the book says you can solve this problem using Eisenstein criterion. That is easy when $x^2+1$ is irreducible mod $p$ as $(p)$ is then prime. What do you do in the other cases?

Comment: Your chain of equalities claims that $[\mathbf{Q}(i, \sqrt[n]{p}) \, : \, \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt[n]{p})] = 2$, but you haven't shown that to be true (using the argument here, that claim is actually equivalent to the claim in the title).

Comment: @BrandonCarter the field is real so it cannot have $i$, so the degree is $2$.

Comment: You can still use Eisenstein's criterion even if $p$ itself is no longer prime.

Comment: @Sorfosh: Sure, but you should mention that in the argument.

Comment: @hardmath yes i know, i just do not know what prime ideal to pick here.

Comment: @BrandonCarter My solution is not really the question here. I am asking for an alternative solution using Eisenstein. I provided my solution so that people do not post that as a solution.

Comment: You are using that $x^n - p$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$, which requires justification, e.g. invoking Eisenstein

Comment: Why is everyone getting hung up on my proof. Yes i am using Eisenstein, on $\mathbb{Z}$. That is not the question lol

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To prove this via Eisenstein's criterion, use the fact that $\mathbb Z[i]$ is a principal ideal domain. In fact, it is Euclidean. Also, for odd primes $p$ in $\mathbb Z$, $p$ remains prime in $\mathbb Z[i]$ for $p=3\mod 4$, and $p$ factors as a product of two distinct primes $p=p_1p_2$ in $\mathbb Z[i]$ for $p=1\mod 4$ (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1736782/over-gaussian-integers-can-every-prime-be-p-equiv-1-text-mod-4-be-express)).

Thus, in either case, there is a prime in $\mathbb Z[i]$ dividing the constant term (and all others except the leading term, since those others are $0$), and whose square does not divide the constant term. So we can apply Eisenstein.

Appropriate proof(s) about the remaining-prime and/or factoring into distinct factors depend on your context... but the explanation may give you some motivation to look at otherwise-technical points.